# How to extract files from rar file in Android by command line tool

Tags: android, adb, appium

As title says, I need to extract files from .rar file and save it on device storage. There are third party tools which supports this. But I was wondering is there any adb /appium /android utility command which provides this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without using a third party tool or app. See the [Android Developer reference for ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html).

If use of third party tools is not out of the question for you (you refer to Appium, after all), and you just want to be able to extract the .rar file from the command line, you might try installing an app which can extract .rar files (there are many) and access the correct activity from the command line using the activity manager. You can view the activities available to you for a given APK using the [Android Asset Packaging Tool](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt) and this command:

```
aapt dump xmltree <path to APK> AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the bullet . Use of  third party application is a risk, because what if they change their app implementation or no support for newer OS or limited support for custom OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would install [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) on your device. This will give you all the commands needed to allow for unzipping the files on your phone. Just disable auto update if you are worried about the application updating.